# How do I map a texture to the sides of an icosahedron?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, opengl-es

I have been trying to develop a 3D game for a long time now. I went through 
[this](http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2009/05/opengl-es-from-ground-up-table-of.html)
 tutorial and found that I didn't know enough to actually make the game.

I am currently trying trying to add a texture to the icosahedron (in the "Look at Basic Drawing" section) he used in the tutorial, but I cannot get the texture on more than one side. The other sides are completely invisible for no logical reason (they showed up perfectly until I added the texture).

Here are my main questions:

- How do I make the texture show up properly without using a million vertices and colors to mimic the results?
- How can I move the object based on a variable that I can set in other functions?

Comment: My opinion is don't.  Use something someone else has already made like Unity.  Creating shapes like textured cubes is simple, getting stuff like textured faces and bodies does involve a ton of vertices and crap.  Which is why it's best left to the pros.  Never mind all the physics you have to handle as part of just making a character walk across a surface.  That, or use something like Cocos2D and make your game 2D.

Comment: @StephenFurlani What I'm doing involves cars, not people. I have made plenty of cars in code, but none of them have textures yet.

Comment: I want to make them by hand because I need them all to be just right. In most 3D modeling programs, I have problems using their shapes to create what I want. Now, would somebody please just tell me how I can add textures to it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to think of your icosahedron as a low poly sphere. I suppose Lamarche's icosahedron has it's center at 0,0,0. Look at this tutorial, it is written for directX but it explains the general principle of sphere texture mapping http://www.mvps.org/directx/articles/spheremap.htm. I used it in my project and it works great. You move the 3D object by applying various transformation matrices. You should have something like this

```
glPushMatrix();
glTranslatef();
draw icosahedron;
glPopMatrix();
```

Here is my code snippet of how I did texCoords for a semisphere shape, based on the tutorial mentioned above

```
    GLfloat *ellipsoidTexCrds;
Vector3D *ellipsoidNorms;

int numVerts = *numEllipsoidVerticesHandle;

ellipsoidTexCrds = calloc(numVerts * 2, sizeof(GLfloat));
ellipsoidNorms = *ellipsoidNormalsHandle;

for(int i = 0, j = 0; i < numVerts * 2; i+=2, j++)
{

    ellipsoidTexCrds[i] = asin(ellipsoidNorms[j].x)/M_PI + 0.5; 
    ellipsoidTexCrds[i+1] = asin(ellipsoidNorms[j].y)/M_PI + 0.5;
}
```

I wrote this about a year and a half ago, but I can remember that I calculated my vertex normals as being equal to normalized vertices. That is possible because when you have a spherical shape centered at (0,0,0), then vertices basically describe rays from the center of the sphere. Normalize them, and you got yourself vertex normals.

And by the way if you're planning to use a 3D engine on the iPhone, use Ogre3D, it's really fast.

hope this helps :)